# How to add a canonical tag on the login page

Tags: magento-1.8, login, seo, canonical

Whats the best way to add a canonical tag to the login page? Would I be best to add something to the head via the layout.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can do this by using method of `addLinkRel()` which is the function of head class `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` that means it reference of head

Please try this.

```
<customer_account_login>
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>canonical</rel><href>/customer/account/login</href></action>
</reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

See [at](http://www.kathirvel.com/magento-canonical-url-for-cms-pages-via-layout-update-xml/)

Comment: How would you set the base url as canonical tags should be absolute paths and not relative eg

Use this structure:  https://www.example.com//customer/account/login
Not this structure: /customer/account/login